# How to get std::hash_set<pair<T1, T2>> to compile and run

Tags: c++, stl, hashset, std-pair

### Problem domain

I have a (potentially) long lists of pairings of data that I need to merge (and perform some logic on) such that there are no duplicates. The pairings were of an `int` type, but due to growth of amount of data, I'm converting it to be pairings of `size_t`, and thus my data type is declared now as `pair<size_t, size_t>`.

The code previously checked for uniqueness by having a `hash_set` and probing into it to see if a given pairing has already been seen and processed.  As a key, it conveniently used `INT64` and built a key using bit shifting and packing:

```
INT64 key = ((INT64)pairsListEntry->first) << 32 | pairsListEntry->second;
```

This was working well since two `int`'s perfectly fit into `INT64` and resulting in unique key.  But for obvious reasons this doesn't work anymore.

### Immediate problem

To adjust for new sizing, I tried to refactor and declare my `hash_set` as:

```
std::hash_set<pair<size_t, size_t>> m_seenPairs;
```

This, however, fails when compiling code that creates an instance of that class with the following error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xhash(71) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'size_t'

This occurs deep inside STL's implementation, in the following function (on the `return` line):

```
template<class _Kty> inline
size_t hash_value(const _Kty& _Keyval)
{   // hash _Keyval to size_t value one-to-one
return ((size_t)_Keyval ^ _HASH_SEED);
}
```

The cause is pretty clear: `pair<T1, T2>` doesn't know how to cast to `size_t` in order to calculate the hash code.

At this point, I'm stuck on how to do get it to work.  Google-foo isn't foo'ing up much.  I saw couple of posts on SO with `std::map` and `pair`, but there it seems "to just work".

The environment is VS2008, x64 platform unmanaged target.

### Things I tried

I tried to provide my own comparer as I've seen [a post that looked at least barely remotely similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374695/simple-c-hash-set-example) as the following:

```
struct pairs_equal_compare
{
    bool operator()(const pair<SampleIdIndex_t, SampleIdIndex_t> & p1, const pair<SampleIdIndex_t, SampleIdIndex_t> & p2) const
    {
        return (p1.first == p2.first) && (p1.second == p2.second);
    }
};

// Holds a set of pairs that are known to exist for deduplication purposes.
stdext::hash_set<pair<SampleIdIndex_t, SampleIdIndex_t>, 
    stdext::hash_compare<pair<SampleIdIndex_t, SampleIdIndex_t>, pairs_equal_compare>> m_seenPairs;
```

This (by the time I got the declarations and struct properly declared) resulted in exactly the same error - realizing now that it doesn't really help bypass internal call to `hash_value` to calculate hash code.

I also briefly tried using `pairs_equal_compare` in place of `hash_compare`, but this produced more compilation errors and looks like a wrong direction to go...

It seems there has to be a reasonable way to get `hash_set` to work on `pair` (or any non-integer type data), but it eludes me on how to accomplish that.

Comment: The code in the post you linked looks nothing like yours.  He has `hash_set<T, hash_T, eq_T>` and you have `hash_set<T, hash_compare<T, T_equal_compare>>`

Comment: @ildjarn From what I've gathered (it's been long since I did `VC++` development) STL went through major changes.  But it seems a bit of a leap to say that in VS2008 `hash_set` is limited to integer types, or is it?

Comment: @MooingDuck I did notice that - but the funny thing is that in that post `hash_set` declaration is not given, but implies template list to take underlying type followed by two simple functors.  Under VS2008, template list is template<class _Kty,
 class _Tr = hash_compare<_Kty, _STD less<_Kty> >,
 class _Alloc = _STD allocator<_Kty> > with last one being allocator rather than functor.  So definitely a mismatch here (that I don't know how to even explain - that's beyond my knowledge of STL).

Comment: @ildjarn VS2008 has it under `stdext` namespace rather than `std`.  It definitely recognizes `hash_set` type and it did build and run when it was `hash_set<INT64>`. So it is definitely **not** due to unknown or undefined type.

Comment: @LB2: That's a very good point, the linked code doesn't remotely work

Comment: @LB2 If the VS neanderthal uses the same deprecated implementation as gnu cxx does, [you may find this helpful](http://pastebin.com/GxCRm1Je).

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking of `unordered_set` all along. You're right, `hash_set` only works with types implicitly convertible to `size_t` by default; you'll need to supply a custom `Traits` argument, with a custom hash object for `std::pair<>` for its first argument (the second, default argument is fine).

Comment: @ildjarn I believe I have it indirectly (there are a bunch of includes) because `pair` which is declared there resolves without issues, and `F12` takes me straight to it in `utility`.

Comment: @ildjarn I did try to use my `pairs_equal_compare` inplace of `hash_compare`, but that turned out to be quite wrong as it's not just a functor but a rather complex 'service' that I don't know quite how to write.  Is this something you can provide a gist of in an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a suitable `Traits` object that behaves like `hash_compare`, i.e., it must define two `operator()`s:

```
size_t operator()(const Key &key) const; // This one returns the hash of key
bool operator()(const Key &first, 
                const Key &second) const; // This one returns true if first is less than second
```

and two integer constants, which you can probably just take from the default implementation:

```
const size_t bucket_size = 4;
const size_t min_buckets = 8;
```

See [documentation of `hash_compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s1byw77%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The code would look like

```
struct pair_comparator{
    typedef std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> Key;
    size_t operator()(const Key &key) const { return /* your hash code here */; }
    bool operator()(const Key &first, 
                const Key &second) const { return first < second; }
    const size_t bucket_size = 4;
    const size_t min_buckets = 8;
};

stdext::hash_set<
    std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>,
    pair_comparator
> s;
```

Edit: The documentation says that you can also derive from a specialization of `hash_compare`, and only override the members you don't like, so:

```
struct pair_comparator : public stdext::hash_compare<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> >{
    typedef std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> Key;
    size_t operator()(const Key &key) const { return /* your hash code here */; }
    bool operator()(const Key &first, 
                const Key &second) const { return first < second; }
};
```

Which should avoid the problem of having to define the `const int` members.

Comment: Except for having to manually provide `bucket_size` and `min_buckets`, I do like this solution better – much less boilerplate.

Comment: @T.C. I'm trying to implement this (one in edit), and now I'm getting a different error `2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xhash(661) : error C2664: 'bool stdext::hash_compare<_Kty>::operator ()(const _Kty &,const _Kty &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const CMainApplication::pair_comparator &'` in `<xhash>'s _Paircc _Hash::equal_range(const key_type& _Keyval) const` function, line `if (!this->comp(this->_Kfn(*_Where), _Keyval))`...
`

Comment: @LB2 Did you pass `hash_compare<pair_comparator>` instead of just `pair_comparator`?

Comment: @T.C. Yes:  `typedef stdext::hash_set<pair<SampleIdIndex_t, SampleIdIndex_t>, stdext::hash_compare<pair_comparator>> SeenPairsHashSet; SeenPairsHashSet *m_dedupSeenPairs;`. And `SampleIdIndex_t` is just a `typedef size_t`.

Comment: @LB2 You should do `typedef stdext::hash_set<pair<SampleIdIndex_t, SampleIdIndex_t>, pair_comparator> SeenPairsHashSet;`.

Comment: @T.C. That made it compile now, thank you - running to see if it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, `stdext::hash_set<>` only works with types that are implicitly convertible to `size_t`. For `std::pair<>`, you'll need to supply an argument to `stdext::hash_compare<>` (for `stdext::hash_set<>`'s `Traits` parameter) that behaves as such, since `std::pair<>` itself does not.

The following works for me with VS2013, and I don't see why it wouldn't also work with VS2008:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <hash_set>

struct pair_hasher
{
    typedef std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> value_type;

    value_type value;

    pair_hasher(value_type const& v) : value(v) { }

    operator std::size_t() const
    {
        return (5381 * 33 ^ value.first) * 33 ^ value.second;
    }
};

bool operator <(pair_hasher const& a, pair_hasher const& b)
{
    return a.value < b.value;
}
```

Then you'll need to declare your `stdext::hash_set<>` instance as such:

```
stdext::hash_set<
    std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>,
    stdext::hash_compare<pair_hasher>
> s;
```

For types other than integral types for the `std::pair<>`, update `pair_hasher::operator std::size_t` as necessary (`operator <` should be fine as-is, as long as the types within the `std::pair<>` are themselves already comparable).