# How does hash_set in C++ work?

Tags: c++, hashset, gcc3

I don't know how to use `hash_set` in C++. I'm incredibly new to this language so I don't understand how to do a lot of things. How do I use the SGI `hash_set` extension so the compiler finally compiles without error? Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef _GAME1_H
#define _GAME1_H

#include "card.h"
#include "deck.h"
#include <ext/hash_set>

const unsigned int TRIALS = 10;

class Game1 {

private:
    // Card::Value is defined in card.h as a public enum:
    // enum Value { NullCard, Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King };
    std::hash_set<Card::Value> *map; // does this really need to be a pointer?

public:
    Game1();
    bool isPair();
    bool isFlush();
    void returnToDeck();
};

#endif
```

When I try to compile I get:

```
In file included from game1.cpp:9:
game1.h:13: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
game1.h:13: error: expected `;' before '<' token
make: *** [game1.o] Error 1
```

1. I don't know what "using-declaration for non-member at class scope" means.
2. Why is the compiler complaining that "expected `;' before '<' token" when I'm basically following the same example as [SGI has on their site](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html)?
3. I am using gcc 3.4.6 so I cannot use `unordered_set`
4. I have looked at [simple C++ hash_set example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374695/simple-c-hash-set-example) but I don't understand why they're using `hash<int> H;` is this relevant?

I'm at a stalemate since I literally cannot figure this out after hours of consulting google.

Comment: "*I am using gcc 3.4.6*" Dear god...

Comment: @ildjarn I know... it's on my school server so there's not much I can do about that

Comment: why not using std::set?

Comment: If this is an assignment, tell your teacher they need to update. `hash_set` was deprecated long ago. We use `unordered_set` today, which is standardized and comes with the latest GCC.

Comment: @dynamic does `std::set` have the same time complexity as a `hash_set`? Based on what I see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) this is the case. All I need to do is look through each card and see if a pair or flush occurs. Pretty easy and with some type of hash set I can do it in O(n) time...

Comment: @djthoms No, `std::set` is a binary tree, so it will be `O(lg N)` for lookup.

Comment: Are you sure that `Card::Value` is a declared in the `public` scoped in `card.h` ?

Comment: @StarPilot yep, yep. It's kind of hard to see but I added that in the comments of my header file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should declare `map` as

```
// answering your other question, most likely it doesn't have to be a pointer.
__gnu_cxx::hash_set<Card::Value> map;
```

(According to the [hash_set source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/ext_2hash__set-source.html))

Also, `map` is not a good name for a variable since it's the name of a standard class. Though it shouldn't be a cause for compilation errors here.